# How to emphasize the fact that the second event is separated from the first one by a big time span?

Tags: phrase-request

How to emphasize the fact that the second event is separated from the first one by a big time span?

For example:

> The arguments that you are presenting are quite ridiculous. Look, you
>   delve into the medieval history, find some faults with the rulers of
>   those times and accuse them of not observing human rights.
>
> Don't you realize that that was an absolutely different dispensation?
>   Humans' minds were different. The common notions were absolutely different. 
>   The very common sense was different!
>
> Just consider the time when 
>   this whole idea of human rights came about.
>   Did it really come about before the Great Schism of 1054 **or, rather, long, long after?**

This "long, long after" is not idiomatic, is it? So, what would be the idiomatic way of expressing that thought?

Comment: Doubling an adjective is idiomatic for emphasis or strengthening. 'A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...".

Comment: Exactly what I say about  drawing and quartering. Who says it was cruel and unusual!!!  It was a different dispensation.

Answer (score 2):

"Long, long after" is idiomatic, we double adjectives for emphasis or strengthening. There is no error here.

It is not highly formal but appropriate to speech (This looks like a transcript of a spoken argument). You could say "many years later" as a possible alternative.